# Getting parent node through child node using XPATH

Tags: python, xpath, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to access parent node of an element in a tree using `e.find('..)'` but it is not working. For the fallowing code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

xml = "<a> <b> </b> </a>"

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
child = root.find('*')

print(child.find('..'))
```

the output is: `None`, why? and, how  can i get parent element (in this case node <\a>)?

I have tried different combination for path and searched the internet, some solution doesn't works and some are specific to the question.

Comment: It won't work. The built in xpath implementation for python doesn't support searching levels higher than the one that called the `find` method.  FYI  in this situation `root` is the `<a>` element

Comment: @Alexander So you mean i can not use `find` or `findall` method to search upward?

Comment: You can but you can't search above the node you called the find or findall function from. If you use lxml as suggested by @Faisal then that won't be an issue anymore

Comment: @Alexander So just to make sure i understood you right, i can only use `..` in situations like this, for example I am on `level n` (that is where i am calling find method) and i can use `..` to go from `level n+m` to `n+m-1` but not above `n` itself?

Comment: Yes....  another example would be if you had a `c`  element as a child to b and `c` had a child `d` then you could do `b.find('.//d/..')` to get `c`  which seems contrived because it is

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet Returns `None` because the parent of the root is the root itself.

Try [lxml](https://github.com/lxml/lxml) Package, `lxml` is a Pythonic binding for the C libraries `libxml2` and `libxslt`.
It is unique in that it combines the speed and XML feature completeness of these libraries with the simplicity of a native Python API, mostly compatible but superior to the well-known ElementTree API.

In your case, we can do something like this;

```
from lxml import etree  # pip install lxml

xml = "<a> <b> </b> </a>"

root = etree.fromstring(xml)

# Get the parent node of b
parent = root.xpath("//b/parent::*")

print(parent[0].tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lxml library, which contains a XPath 1.0 implementation:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as let
>>> doc = let.fromstring("<a> <b> </b> </a>")
>>> doc.xpath('//*[b]') # return all nodes with a direct `b` child
[<Element a at 0x7fffef3ed8c0>]
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to get the parent with ElementTree, but you cannot use `find()` on the child directly.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) states:

> `..` selects the parent element. Returns `None` if the path attempts to reach the ancestors of the start element (the element `find` was called on).

Demo:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

xml = "<a> <b> </b> </a>"

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
child = root.find('*')

# This does not work because we are calling find() on the child element
print(child.find('..'))   # None

# This works because we are calling find() on the root element
print(root.find("*/.."))  # <Element 'a' at 0x000002088B2B4B30>
```